# How to set FireMonkey form icon runtime in Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm creating an application for Windows and OS X using Firemonkey Framework with Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and can't set application or form icon dynamically.

In VCL project I've used following code:

```
Form1.Icon.LoadFromFile()
```

or

```
Application.Icon.LoadFromFile()
```

But there are no such properties or methods in FMX. Is there any way to set project icon otherwise than in Project -> Options menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your uses list `{$IFDEF WIN32}WinApi.Windows,FMX.Platform.Win,{$ENDIF}`

```
procedure setFormIcon(Form: TForm; FileName: String);
  var Icon : NativeUInt;
begin
  {$IFDEF WIN32}
  ICON := LoadImage(0,PWideChar(Filename),IMAGE_ICON,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE OR LR_DEFAULTSIZE OR LR_SHARED);
  SetClassLong(FmxHandleToHWND(Form.Handle), GCL_HICON, icon);
  {$ENDIF}
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  setFormIcon(Form1,'my icon path.ico');
end;
```

Comment: Okay. How about OS X?

Comment: And ths proc sets only Form icon. Is there any way to set Application icon?

Answer (score 0):

In the 10.2 Rio sources, I see that the `function TPlatformWin.CreateWindow`, which is used to create a window in the Windows, have only this line to provide a window's icon:

`WindowClass.hIcon := LoadIconW(MainInstance, PChar('MAINICON'));`

And `function TPlatformWin.CreateAppHandle` have an absolutely same code! So, **we have not a direct way to set app or form icon through FireMonkey components.**

At Windows You still can use WinAPI message `WM_SETICON` (`SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, MyIconHandle);`), but I have not tried that and do not know any troubles in this way.

Also in Windows we may use `TTaskbarBase` and `TPreviewClipRegion` classes to the more precise and functional way of TaskBar interactions.

P.S. I do not know, what we have for same requirements at OS X.